# Имя файла должно начинаться со строки но не содержать другую

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Необходимо выбрать из листа имен файлов только те которые удовлетворяют следующему условию: начинается с 'web_debug' после этого любые символы, но не должно содержать строку 'decrypted'.

Например:

```
web_debug.log
web_debug.decrypted.log
web_debug_some.log.decrypted
web_debug.2323232323232.log
```

Должны пройти только первый и последний файлы. Мой вариант плохо работает:

```
^(?i)(eeidweb_debug)+(?!(decrypted))
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/KDqmbi/1

Answer (score 6):

```
^(?!.*decrypted.*)web_debug.*$
```

- `(?!.*decrypted.*)` - сперва накладываем условие, что строка не содержит подстроки `decrypted`
- `web_debug.*` - затем указываем остальные возможные варианты

Comment: большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Ваш вариант, но рабочий. И он сначала проверяет наличие в начале строки подстроки `web_debug` и только потом отсутствие далее подстроки `decrypted`:

```
^(?i)web_debug(?!.*decrypted).*
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/KDqmbi/1

P.S. Если регистр имеет значение, то следует убрать `(?i)`.

P.P.S. С уменьшенной жадностью:

```
^(?i)web_debug(?!.*?decrypted).*
```